# How do you verify that a CRS projection is equidistant in R?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I'm working with some shapefiles in R, primarily using the "sf" package. I've written a function that finds the distance in a shapefile to the nearest polygon with some particular characteristic (say, the nearest "flagged" polygon), using the st_distance() function.

But I'd like to add a check that the CRS of the function's shapefile argument uses an equidistant projection, so that I can prevent users from improperly passing in shapefiles that are (for example) in lat/long (producing distances in "degrees", which are not a consistent size). Ideally it would work something like this:

```
#Shapefile with CRS EPSG:4326
is_equidistant_projection(lat_long_shapefile)
#Returns FALSE

#Shapefile with CRS EPSG:4087 World Equidistant Cylindrical
is_equidistant_projection(equidistant_cylindrical_shapefile)
#Returns TRUE
```

Comment: Equidistant Cylindrical doesn't have the Equidistant property, because it's cylindrical -- It's only "equidistant along any meridian and both standard parallels. Shape, scale, and area distortion increase with the distance from the standard parallels." ([source](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/equidistant-cylindrical.htm)). So the second result should be FALSE as well. If you want to calculate geodesic distance, you should probably use a geodesic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing as a fully equidistant projected system such that all distances (x,y)->(x',y') in projected coordinates are linearly related to the great-circle distance between them on the globe.

Equidistant projected coordinate systems only have that property from special points (eg poles for polar azimuthal equidistant) or along special lines (like the equator for plate caree). Projected coordinate systems for small areas, or things like UTM zones, are designed to have good (but not perfect) equidistant properties over their whole region of support. You may have to rely on your user inputting data with an appropriate projected CRS for their data points.

To determine if a CRS has an equidistant property from a PROJ or WKT string would involve a lookup-table of the properties of the projection. For example the PROJ string of ESPG:27700 has "+proj=tmerc" and you would then have to see look up the `tmerc` (transverse mercator) was equidistant. I don't know of a readymade table of projection codes to properties but Wikipedia has something that could be used to build such a thing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections Note that my PROJ installation has 160 different projection types shown via `proj -lp` on the command line, so potentially you'd have to put all those in a table with their equidistant status.

One useful function in the `sf` package for this is `st_is_longlat`, which will at least tell you if the CRS is spherical/ellipsoidal (such as 4326 or any other lat-long coordinate system) or projected (like a UTM zone or some national grid system).